# Intellij How to open file in module

Tags: intellij-idea

I have multi module project opened in my Intellij. lets say the module names are

```
module1 
module2 
module3
```

I have one class called `hello.java` in all three module. now how can i open `hello.java` in `module2` while i press `ctrl + n` . I know one way is typing `/module2/hello`. But here the problem is my module names are big. so typing the whole thing is not so fun.

So is there any short-cut way???

Comment: `CTRL + N` should give you three results for `Hello`, and also show you the modules that each belongs to.  Is that not doing it?  What happens when you use `CTRL + N`?

Comment: this is figure of speech. don't take it literally. I may have ten file with same name. and i am not always looking java file

Comment: So you're using `SHIFT+CTRL+N` then?  Again, what do you see when that happens?

Comment: I see 3 items but i want to see only one. or in broader case i see list of 10 item and i want to see 1 item

Comment: ...But they're all named the same.  You'll still get 10 different results for similarly named files or classes.

Comment: yes i know that. that's why i am asking if there ware a better way that i don't know of. e.g. if there was a way i could mark module 2 as m2 then i could search m2/hello.java; something like that

Comment: Have you tried that?  I've done that sort of thing when looking for similarly named classes, and it generally works.  Better yet - have you tried doing it by their package name?  I'm hoping that the files are the same, but not the package structure (and that implies another major issue).

Comment: It might surprise you, but the package name are exactly same. only difference is the module names. it's a ten years old ERP code :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can achieve this in two ways.

- hit CTRL+N to *Go to Class* and then type partial module name and the class name separated by a dot, e.g. `dule2.hello` to find class `module2.hello`
- hit CTRL+SHIFT+N to *Go to File* and then do as above but with path separators instead, e.g. `/dule2/hello`

Therefore you don't need to type the full module name but are still able to filter arbitrarily large numbers of modules.

Comment: I know this as i said in my question. but i was looking for a way to set variable. e.g. if i could put m2=module2  somewhere, then i could call m2/hello. or something similar like this

Comment: isn't typing only a subset of the module name a shortcut? You said in the question "my module names are big. so typing the whole thing is not so fun"

Comment: in the comment below my question i said that i have many module / package with almost same/same name. so this wont work. but thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

Hit shift twice in rapid succession and then type the file name.